# Searching for data by two parameter numbers with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have problems with where CodeIgniter on the query, which I want to find the data between the two parameters. like the example below.

Controllers

```
public function search_genus() {    
    $data = array(
        'find_kebun' => $this->my_model->find(),
        'content' =>'my_view'
    );      
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
}
```

Models

```
public function find() {    
    $search = $this->input->post('param');

    $A = "1 - 10";
    $B = "11- 15";

    if ($search = $A ) {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                              ->from('my_tables')
                              ->where('genus', 1 > 10)
                              ->get();      
            return $query->result();    
    }else if ($search = $B ) {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                              ->from('my_tables')
                              ->where('genus', 11 > 15)
                              ->get();      
            return $query->result();    
    }

}
```

Views

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/search_genus"   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select name="param">
        <option value="A">1 - 10</option>
        <option value="B">11 - 15</option>
    </select>

    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
</form>
```

after I run error at where how to solve?

Comment: thansk @splash58, but i want display value 1 to 10, and if B = just value 11 to 15

Answer (score 1):

Try this
- Controller:

```
public function search_genus() {   
    $search = $this->input->post('param'); 
    $data = array(
        'find_kebun' => $this->my_model->find($search ),
        'content' =>'my_view'
    );      
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data); 
}
```

And Model

```
 public function find($search) {    

        $A = "1 - 10";
        $B = "11- 15";
if ($search == "A" ) {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                              ->from('my_tables')
                              ->where('genus', 1 > 10)
                              ->get();      
            return $query->result();    
    }else if ($search == "B" ) {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                              ->from('my_tables')
                              ->where('genus', 11 > 15)
                              ->get();      
            return $query->result();    
    }
```